# Calculate and plot the mean square displacement of particle trajectories from a txt file on Python

Tags: python

I want to calculate and plot the MSD of particle trajectories, to find out whether the trajectories are due to pure diffusion in the medium or whether they are constrained or subject to an applied force. I've tried to do this exercise using Python, but I always have the same problem: either my graphs are all the same even though my data sets are different, or my MSD is a horizontal line.

Here's my code with which I'm trying to solve the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Loading data from the txt file
data = np.loadtxt('/Users/arthurcoet/Documents/PhD COËT/CiNAM/Python/Exercices/Dtxt1.txt')

# Retrieving data columns
temps = data[:, 0]
indices = data[:, 1]
positions_x = data[:, 2]
positions_y = data[:, 3]

# Calculation of the MSD for each particle
particle_indices = np.unique(indices)
msd_particles = []

for particle_index in particle_indices:
    indices_particle = np.where(indices == particle_index)[0]
    x_particle = positions_x[indices_particle]
    y_particle = positions_y[indices_particle]
    displacements = np.sqrt((x_particle - x_particle[0])**2 + (y_particle - y_particle[0])**2)
    msd_particle = np.mean(displacements ** 2)
    msd_particles.append(msd_particle)

# Calculation of average MSD
msd_mean = np.mean(msd_particles)

# Plot of average MSD against time
plt.plot(temps, msd_mean * np.ones_like(temps), '-')
plt.xlabel('Temps')
plt.ylabel('MSD')
plt.title('MSD moyen en fonction du temps')
plt.show()
```

I'll also show you an extract from my txt file, the format is as follows: time, particle index, X, Y :

```
2.000000000000000042e-02    1.000000000000000000e+00    1.240807597782861649e+00    -3.785534313700077980e-01
2.000000000000000042e-02    2.000000000000000000e+00    -7.309480801080029400e-01   -7.170078639286830979e-01
2.000000000000000042e-02    3.000000000000000000e+00    8.098986703909789586e-01    5.815296326847829711e-01
2.000000000000000042e-02    4.000000000000000000e+00    2.750517661172900349e-03    5.522082763915119319e-01
2.000000000000000042e-02    5.000000000000000000e+00    9.127289184940016176e-01    5.289936832099206843e-01
2.000000000000000042e-02    6.000000000000000000e+00    1.340115717383320693e+00    -2.206167086146532119e-01
2.000000000000000042e-02    7.000000000000000000e+00    -9.347632084034850353e-01   -1.031270972401856945e+00
2.000000000000000042e-02    8.000000000000000000e+00    -1.564283425436366892e+00   9.906037061246882880e-01
2.000000000000000042e-02    9.000000000000000000e+00    -1.092736507472809315e-01   -7.019693105410058642e-01
2.000000000000000042e-02    1.000000000000000000e+01    1.079635002230163246e-02    1.936345833496776025e+00
```

And the images of the plot of the particles trajectories :

[image: Trajectories plot]

By any chance, have you also encountered this problem and if so, do you know how to remedy it?